# load csv file by matching the existing id and add property the relationship

Tags: neo4j

I have a graph which contains nodes labeled Diseases, they have as a propriety a unique id(cui) and relationships Has_child, Has_descendant. I would like to load a CSV file and add some property on the relationships by matching the id.

```
USING PERIODIC COMMIT 
LOAD CSV WITH HEADERS FROM 'file:///Descendant_distance.csv' AS line 
FIELDTERMINATOR '\t'
MERGE (d:Disease{id: line.CUI_SRC})
(n:Disease{id: line.CUI_DST})
 (d)-[r:HAS_CHILD|HAS_DESCENDANT]->(n)
 on match set 
    r.distance = line.DISTANCE,
    r.SAB = line.SAB;
```

I tried this, for me is logic that it should work but I have an error

```
    (Neo.ClientError.Statement.SyntaxError: Invalid input '(': expected whitespace, comment, a relationship pattern, ON, FROM GRAPH, CONSTRUCT, LOAD CSV, START, MATCH, UNWIND, MERGE, CREATE UNIQUE, CREATE, SET, DELETE, REMOVE, FOREACH, WITH, CALL, RETURN, ';' or end of input (line 5, column 1 (offset: 150))  "(n:Disease{id: line.CUI_DST})"
```

I expect that at the end I will have the 2 properties added to the relationship, without affecting/modifying the rest of the data.
Can anyone help me solve this query?

Comment: USING PERIODIC COMMIT 
LOAD CSV WITH HEADERS FROM 'file:///Descendant_distance.csv' AS line 
FIELDTERMINATOR '\t'
MERGE (d:Disease{id:line.CUI_SRC})-[r:HAS_CHILD]->(n:Disease{id:line.CUI_DST})
 on match set 
 r.distance = line.DISTANCE,
 r.SAB = line.SAB;  This query starts loading, i dont have any error but is not performing.. i waited 10 minutes and still loading. How can i make it faster? should i asert an index to some property?

Comment: please give us a copy (or sample) of your data so that we can try it on our own. file:///Descendant_distance.csv

Comment: CUI_SRC,CUI_DST,REL_TYPE,DISTANCE,SAB
C0000729,C0344375,child,1,NCI
C0000735,C0001618,child,1,SNOMEDCT_US
C0000735,C0001624,child,1,SNOMEDCT_US
C0000735,C0003614,child,1,SNOMEDCT_US
C0000735,C0003810,child,1,SNOMEDCT_US
C0000735,C0004991,child,1,SNOMEDCT_US
C0000735,C0004997,child,1,SNOMEDCT_US
C0000735,C0005426,child,1,SNOMEDCT_US
C0000735,C0005684,child,1,SNOMEDCT_US
C0000735,C0005695,child,1,SNOMEDCT_US
C0000735,C0006160,child,1,SNOMEDCT_US
C0000735,C0007102,child,1,SNOMEDCT_US
C0000735,C0007112,child,1,SNOMEDCT_US

Comment: I don't know how to actually put a csv file here, I have in my graph aleady created all my nodes having unique id (cui) and i want on the relationship between 2 nodes to add 2 proprieties from the csv.

Comment: If the nodes are already created then no need to do a merge and match is sufficiently enough.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The nodes are already created so you can do a Match, Set commands instead.

```
USING PERIODIC COMMIT  
LOAD CSV WITH HEADERS FROM 'file:///Descendant_distance.csv' AS line 
FIELDTERMINATOR '\t'
MATCH (d:Disease{id: line.CUI_SRC}), 
(n:Disease{id: line.CUI_DST}), 
(d)-[r:HAS_CHILD|HAS_DESCENDANT]->(n)
SET r.distance = line.DISTANCE,
    r.SAB = line.SAB;
```